# Could life as we know it exist if there were no speed limit and no special-relativistic effects?

Tags: light, relativity

My perception based on reading popular-science articles is this:

1. Nothing can exceed speed of light in vacuum
2. Speed of light is the same for all observers, irrelevant of their own relative speed

But my understanding, perchance completely misguided, is that these things matter mostly when we deal with huge velocities, approaching light speed - so not something organisms on earth deal with in their slow lives. I understand also that motion of planets in our solar systems can largely/roughly be described by Newtonian mechanics. I do acknowledge that relativistic effects need to be taken into account in various pieces of actual technology used by humans but they seem to be just minor error-reducing corrections.

So, taking all this into account - can Earth-like or our-solar-system-like thing exist in a world where electromagnetic waves have no speed limit and their speed is not the same for all observers?

**UPDATE**

@AlexP said:

> The speed of light is directly linked to the electromagnetic
> properties of the vacuum, $c=1/\sqrt{ε_0μ_0}$. If there is no speed
> limit, this means that the speed of light is different for different
> observers; and since the speed of light is directly linked to the
> strength of electromagnetic forces, this means that chemistry is
> different for different observers. Non-uniform chemistry makes the
> existence of life . . . difficult. (And about those error-reducing
> corrections: satellite-based navigation systems such as GPS do not
> work without applying relativistic corrections.)

This then answers my question as a straight "no" with a nice explanation. Thank you. If you post it as the answer I'll be able to accept it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to mean with "electromagnetic waves have no speed limit and behave more like a very fast sound wave". Sound waves have a speed limit, too, which is also way slower than the speed of light.

Comment: The speed of light is directly linked to the electromagnetic properties of the vacuum, $c = 1 / \sqrt{\varepsilon_0 \mu_0}$. If there is no speed limit, this means that the speed of light is different for different observers; and since the speed of light is directly linked to the strength of electromagnetic forces, this means that *chemistry* is different for different observers. Non-uniform chemistry makes the existence of life . . . difficult. (And about those error-reducing corrections: satellite-based navigation systems such as GPS *do not work* without applying relativistic corrections.)

Comment: P.S. If you want a world where the speed of light is different for different observers *and* you want to write a hard-science-fiction story *then* you need to develop a resonably complete description of the physics of your world; because the physics of the real world absolutely requires that the speed of light in a vacuum be the same for all observers. On the other hand, if you do not want a particularly hard sci-fi story, then just forget that light travels at finite speed and just tell the story.

Comment: If you want to have some science, take a look of theories of the Aether, before and after relativity there have been various proponents of an Aether, including Einstein. In a your universe by having the Aether having different properties in different places you can choose your light speed. I think this has been done by various authors.

Comment: Ultraviolet catastrophe...

Comment: @AlexP I don't think the chemistry will be a problem--the changes in chemistry as you move over a planet will be very small.  It would mean that starships would be deadly, though.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: *"As you move over a planet:"* Thinking at the wrong scale. "You" are not the subject of chemistry. Electrons are. And they move at high speed in different directions.

Comment: @AlexP High speed in different directions but they don't undergo big speed **changes**, just direction changes.  I think there would be a stable chemistry, albeit substantially different than Earth chemistry.

Comment: @AlexP However, this got me thinking--what about the strong nuclear force?  Would removing the speed limit change it's range and thus radically upset atomic physics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weight and balance of chemistry would change radically.

Electrons, protons and neutrons get a tiny bit of intrinsic mass from their charge (neutrons from the charges of the quarks their made of) and the Higgs field, but most of the mass comes from the magnification of that tiny amount of initial charge due to the incredible speed they are moving at. Just increasing the speed limit will re-order the orbitals where the various pushes and pulls around the atom have local minimums. No speed  limit at all would, I think eliminate orbitals entirely. And chemistry as we know it. So also biology (chemistry). Might be some new combinations of balancing forces would arise, but it would be very different.

Answer (score 3):

Remember $E = mc^2$? Einstein originally wrote it another way:

$$ m = \frac{E^2}{c^2} $$

Which is the same, but makes it easier to drive the point: mass and energy are just two different measures of the very same thing. The conversion between kilograms and joules is mediated by the constant $c^2$.

If $c$ were to trend towards the infinite, you would need an infinite amount of joules to form any amount of mass at all. This means that the universe would have never evolved past the [Planck Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_early_universe#Planck_epoch). In layman terms, matter would be present, but it would have no mass and no particles would exist. All you would have is quantum fluctuations in space.

Answer (score 0):

**It depends on what else you are willing to give up.**

As you have noticed, the speed limit for the universe is not an arbitrary law enforced by a law enforcement office.  It is a consequence of the equations we use to model reality (and assuming we've done a good job of those equations, a consequence of reality).  To get rid of the limit, you must select equations to change, and then reflect those changes all the way through physics in a self-consistent way (or at least as consistent as gravity and quantum physics are today).

If you do a hackjob of this, simply removing equations that look unseemly, its like curing cancer with a hacksaw.  It is unlikely your patient will survive.  Other changes need to be made.  James Mcllean mentions in his answer that the masses of the particles we use in subatomic physics are tied to relativity.  Those would need to change.  And you could do that.  Are you willing to let angels move the particles along their pre-ordained trajectories?  If so, you could do particularly brutal things to modern scientific theory, as long as you are willing to replace it with the divine force needed to make it happen.  But, practically speaking, it shouldn't have to come to that.  "Smaller" tweaks, if desired, can do the job.  A little mass here, a little energy there.  Some replacement for the connection between electricity and magnetism... you get the idea.

The Newtonian physics you want for planetary motion are not difficult.  They are rather simple 2nd order equations that only need hold true at slow speeds.
There are many systems which can meet those needs.  Indeed, I would argue relativity is one of the kookier ways you can have that physics.  If you want more of modern scientific theory to survive, however, it could get trickier.

If you want a "big bang" which is identical in behavior to the one we theorize today, it could be difficult.  In those early phases, the energy densities were extremely high, and that makes relativistic effects even more important.  You would have to fudge more things.  You might need more of an "epoch" where the rules shift to make things a reality (kind of like our "inflationary period," although we claim this is not a "rules change" as much as just a different regime in the same rules).

Want the Standard Model? That could be harder.  The Standard Model is steeped upon the assumptions tied into assumptions of how observable values propagates.  It would be difficult to remove these without substantially changing then nature of the model.

What about life itself?  Could life exist?  This is a thorny question, that we don't yet have an answer for.  Life is frustratingly brittle.  Every time we change little things like this we find reasons life as we know it cannot exist.  And yet, life is inscrutably robust.  To dare quote a function movie as though it were truth, "Nature finds a way."  Indeed it starts to feel hubris to think that this is the only possible way something like life occurs.